# Конструктор с параметром-кортежем в Python - пример из Intuit.ru

Tags: python, ооп

Пример из курса Python

```
class Line:
  def __init__(self, (x, y), (x1, y1)):
    self._b = (x, y)
    self._e = (x1, y1)
  def length(self):
    import math
    return math.sqrt((self._b[0]-self._e[0])**2 + (self._b[1]-self._e[1])**2)
```

У меня Python 3.4. Во 2 строке дает ошибку Invalid sintax.

Comment: Поищите что-нибудь посвежее, в вашем интуите примеры написаны для старого питона

Comment: [PEP 3113 -- Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой синтаксис некорректен для Python 3.
Правильный код:

```
class Line:
  def __init__(self, first, second):
    self._b = first # записали в self._b кортеж (1, 2)
    self._e = second # записали в self._e кортеж (3, 4)
  def length(self):
    import math
    return math.sqrt((self._b[0]-self._e[0])**2 + (self._b[1]-self._e[1])**2)

line = Line((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

Класс принимает **два** аргумента: `first` и `second` - мы передаем в него два аргумента, каждый их которых является кортежом с двух элементов.

Comment: Ответ частично неверный, в Python 2.7 код из вопроса прекрасно работает без каких-либо изменений

Comment: Но написали, что используют Python 3.4

Comment: Это у автора, а что про это написано на самом интуите, нам никто не стал рассказывать)